# Problemas con z index en carousel en bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola estoy haciendo [esta pagina](http://qkstudiodemo.com/santamaria/html/) el problema que tengo es con el carousel principal donde la imagen del producto (imagen derecha) quisiera que este por encima de las lineas (osea los ul) del rotador, Le estuve poniendo z index y no me responde.

Comment: Quieres que las lineas con las que se muestra en que imagen del slide se encuentra no se vean?

Comment: lo que quiero es que el producto quede por encima de las lineas.

Comment: Para eso, es más sencillo que std haga su propia slider... por que la estructura de bootstrap no le permitirá hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a ocultar las barras del primer slider, podrías agregar la propiedad en tu hoja de estilos:

```
.carousel-indicators{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: claro! si eso si, pero el diseño que me piden es que las barras esten y que el producto se posicione por encima de las lineas.

Comment: Te refieres que las barras se encuentren más abajo que el slider? Osea que bajen un espacio como llegando al container blanco.?'

Comment: ahi edito y adjunto una imagen de como quiero

Comment: ahi esta! o de ultima si saben de alguna pagina donde pueda encontrar un carousel parecido.

Comment: @MarianoFranco para lograr lo que quieres en la imagen debes cambiar hasta la estructura HTML y al cambiarla posiblemente deje de funcionar correctamente el carousel...

Comment: OK! entonces como lo podria hacer? tendrías algún ejemplo como para mostrame? el ejemplo de carousel lo saque de acá https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120961/problemas-con-carousel-caption-en-un-carousel-en-bootstrap?noredirect=1#comment225098_120961

Answer (score 0):

Es una gran pregunta, mira te explico cómo funciona esto.

El z-index de tu imagen no funciona en relación al z-index del OL porque si bien es mayor el número, la imagen se encuentra dentro de un padre div que no es el mismo que el padre del OL.

Por lo que z-index funciona siempre en relación al padre.

Un ejemplo de código de lo que hablo es este:

```
<div class="padre1" style="z-index: 1">
  <div class="hijo1" style="z-index: 10000"></div>
</div>

<div class="padre2" style="z-index: 2">
  <div class="hijo2" style="z-index: 0"></div>
</div>
```

En este caso que te presento, el "hijo1" quedará por debajo del "hijo2" porque son "presos" de sus correspondientes padres.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, te recomiendo reformules la estructura de tu HTML para intentar tener el OL y la imágen bajo el mismo padre y des esa forma jugar con ellos hasta lograr lo que quieres.

Te mando un saludo y espero haberte ayudado con mis vueltas al explicar algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @jonathanSchell

Comment: Me cuentas como te fue, saludos!